Jenkins and Agent inside of Docker
I have a working solution.  I was wondering whether there is an simpler easier one!  The idea was to get Jenkins and an Agent up and running in Docker.  Without any manual intervention.  Ideally
I just want that secret hard coding to save the download and process of xml in the agent.
docker-compose.yaml
Defines the 2 services - jenkins and python-agent.
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - "${JENKINS_LOCAL_PORT}:${JENKINS_PRIVATE_PORT}"
      - "${JNLP_LOCAL_PORT}:50000"
    volumes:
      - ./.cache/dev/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./.cache/dev/jenkins/jenkins_config:/var/jenkins_home/jenkins_config
      - ./dev_env/services/jenkins/server/init.groovy.d:/usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
    restart: always

  python-agent:
    build:
      context: ./dev_env/services/jenkins/agent
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: python-agent
    environment:
      - JENKINS_URL=${JENKINS_PRIVATE_BASE_URL}
      - JENKINS_AGENT_NAME=${JENKINS_AGENT_NAME}
      - JENKINS_SECRET=${JENKINS_AGENT_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
    ports:
      - "${PYTHON_AGENT_LOCAL_PORT}:${PYTHON_AGENT_PRIVATE_PORT}"

    volumes:
      - ./dev_env/services/jenkins/agent/agent_setup.sh:/agent_setup.sh
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/agent_setup.sh"]

volumes:
  jenkins_home:

dev_env/services/jenkins/server/init.groovy.d/create-agent.groovy
This will register the python agent in docker.  Problem is, I want to set its secret when I register it!
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import hudson.model.*

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def nodeName = "python-agent"
def remoteFS = "/home/jenkins/agent"
def numExecutors = 1
def labels = ""
def secret = "agent007" // Use your actual secret here

if (jenkins.getNode(nodeName) == null) {
    def launcher = new JNLPLauncher(null, null) // No tunnel, no custom JVM args
    def node = new DumbSlave(
        nodeName,                      // Node name
        "Description of the agent",    // Description
        remoteFS,                      // Remote root directory
        numExecutors.toString(),       // Number of executors
        Node.Mode.NORMAL,              // Usage mode
        labels,                        // Labels
        launcher,                      // Launch method
        RetentionStrategy.Always.INSTANCE, // Retention strategy
        new LinkedList<>()
    )
    jenkins.addNode(node)
    println("Node ${nodeName} created.")
} else {
    println("Node ${nodeName} already exists.")
}

dev_env\services\jenkins\agent\dockerfile
Use the jenkins agent as a base and install python.
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

USER jenkins

dev_env\services\jenkins\agent\agent_setup.sh
Does the heavy lifting by downloading the jnlp file, parsing it and then finding the secret.  This makes me feel uncomfortable looking at the xml.
#!/bin/bash

NODE_NAME=${JENKINS_AGENT_NAME}
WORK_DIR="/home/jenkins/agent"
USER="admin"
PASSWORD="Password123#"
MAX_RETRIES=30  # Max wait time (30 retries ~ 150 seconds with 5-second intervals)
RETRY_INTERVAL=5  # Time to wait (seconds) between retries
SECRET="Not set"

function wait_for_jenkins {
    echo "Waiting for Jenkins to be ready..."
    local retries=0
    while [[ $retries -lt $MAX_RETRIES ]]; do
        if curl -fs "${JENKINS_URL}/login" >/dev/null; then
            echo "Jenkins is ready!"
            return 0
        fi
        echo "Jenkins is not ready yet. Retrying in ${RETRY_INTERVAL}s..."
        sleep $RETRY_INTERVAL
        ((retries++))
    done
    echo "Error: Jenkins did not become ready within the timeout period."
    exit 1
}

# Download agent.jar
function download_agent_jar {
    echo "Downloading agent.jar..."
    curl -sO "${JENKINS_URL}/jnlpJars/agent.jar"
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error: Failed to download agent.jar."
        exit 1
    fi
}

# Retrieve secret dynamically
function get_agent_secret {
    echo "Retrieving secret for node: ${NODE_NAME}..." >&2

    # Fetch the full content
    local full_content=$(curl -u "${USER}:${PASSWORD}" \
        "${JENKINS_URL}/computer/${NODE_NAME}/slave-agent.jnlp")

    local secret=$(echo "$full_content" | awk -F'<argument>|</argument>' '/<argument>/{print $2; exit}')
    echo "full_content: $full_content" >&2

    if [[ -z "$secret" ]]; then
        # echo "Error: Failed to retrieve the secret for the node." >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    # echo "Returning secret: $secret" >&2 # Ensure the secret is echoed for return
    echo "Secret: $secret"
    echo "$secret"
}

function start_agent {
    local secret=$1
    echo "Starting agent for node: ${NODE_NAME}..."
    java -jar agent.jar -url "${JENKINS_URL}/" -secret "${secret}" -name "${NODE_NAME}" -workDir "${WORK_DIR}" -webSocket
}

echo "JENKINS_URL: ${JENKINS_URL}"

# Main script flow
wait_for_jenkins
download_agent_jar
SECRET=$(get_agent_secret)

start_agent "$SECRET"

JNLP XML
This is what the agent downloads to parse.
<jnlp>
    <application-desc>
        <argument>a5cba26b8e2d7bc34ba1005a7fa2f85c0beacfadf254f78e23295cf9eff4a2ac</argument>
        <argument>python-agent</argument>
        <argument>-workDir</argument>
        <argument>/home/jenkins/agent</argument>
        <argument>-internalDir</argument>
        <argument>remoting</argument>
        <argument>-url</argument>
        <argument>http://jenkins:8080/</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>

podman.env
JENKINS_LOCAL_PORT=10002
JENKINS_PRIVATE_PORT=8080
JNLP_LOCAL_PORT=50000
PYTHON_AGENT_LOCAL_PORT=10003
PYTHON_AGENT_PRIVATE_PORT=50000
JENKINS_AGENT_NAME=python-agent
JENKINS_AGENT_SECRET=agent007
JENKINS_BASE_URL=http://localhost:10002
JENKINS_PRIVATE_BASE_URL=http://jenkins:8080

Compose
To up everything:
podman compose `
    -f "docker-compose.dev.yml" `
    --env-file=podman.env up `
    -d `
    --force-recreate

Python Agent In Jenkins
In the Web Admin (http://localhost:10002/computer/python%2Dagent/):
curl -sO http://localhost:10002/jnlpJars/agent.jar;java -jar agent.jar -url
http://localhost:10002/ -secret 356af4e95e36c130fa704745b20360e74f210437979ac63946a2d09b9525a70f -name "python-agent" -webSocket -workDir "/home/jenkins/agent"

Other Things of Note
You can retrieve a secret using the Groovy script console in the Jenkins web front end (http://localhost:10002/manage/script):
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def nodeName = "python-agent" // Replace with your agent's name
def node = Jenkins.instance.getNode(nodeName)

if (node) {
    def secret = node.getComputer()?.getJnlpMac()
    if (secret) {
        println("The secret for agent '${nodeName}' is: ${secret}")
    } else {
        println("Secret for agent '${nodeName}' not found.")
    }
} else {
    println("Agent '${nodeName}' does not exist.")
}

Result:
The secret for agent 'python-agent' is: 221cb384d69f99231f805cbf7dbb61a50d668831e16bfc0bc6f9b6637c0a4c29
Improving
Ideally I just wanted to hard code the secret up front - agent007.  So that when Jenkins was setup it would register the agent with it.  And when the agent started, it would know to use that secret.  The problem is when you register the agent in the create-agent.groovy it ends up with a random secret.
Can we control the secret and set it?
